# Laravel Integrity constraint error not returning JSON in controller

Tags: php, json, laravel-5, jwt

I'm in the process of learning Laravel to create a restful API. The following code is currently talking to the Users table and creating new records in it. However, when a duplicate email request hits the DB, the exception that I thought would be caught (to return a JSON error) is not, and I get a Laravel exception instead which appears to be a 'QueryException' that is deeper down within the app.

The message is as follows:

> ```
> QueryException in Connection.php line 761:
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'email' in ....
> ```

How do I best catch this error in my application and return a Json response as opposed to a Laravel one? am I missing something obvious?

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User as User;
use JWTAuth;
use Response;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
  public function __construct(Request $request){
        $this->request = $request;
  }

  public function signup()
  {
    $email = $this->request->input('email');
    $password = $this->request->input('password');
    $credentials['email'] = $email;
    $credentials['password'] = $password;
    $credentials['name'] = 'Name';

    try {
         $user = User::create($credentials);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return Response::json(['error' => 'User already exists.'], HttpResponse::HTTP_CONFLICT);
    }

    $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);
    return Response::json(compact('token'));
  }


}
```

Comment: Try `catch (\Exception $e)`

Comment: @ka_lin - what is this witchcraft? This works :) Can you elaborate on what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the `} catch (Exception $e) {` into `} catch (\Exception $e) {`

Since your current namespace is `App\Http\Controllers\Api;`

PHP tries to catch the exception with the name `App\Http\Controllers\Api\Exception;` - which clearly does not exist.

To escape the current namespace and catch a native exception you will need a **backslash**: `\Exception` - this is it's full qualifier name.

Alternatively you can add at the top of your script like any other library or smth... `use \Exception as Exception;`